# A substitute for Visio for E-R modelling

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, dia

I need to submit a college project proposal for a dbms on airline reservation systems along with the E-R diagram. Microsoft Visio is unaffordable so I tried using Dia v0.97.2.

Its easy to use but I can't figure out a way to get the diagram on a word document. I used the Copy diagram option but that doesn't get the complete diagram for me.

I tried including snapshots but since my reputation is less than 10 I couldn't.

Also what entities can be included for this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like steffen said, export is a good option! i would suggest exporting as png though, and then you can just drag'n'drop that image into your word document. personally, this is what i usually do :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to export your Dia diagram in EMF or WMF format? This usually works quite well. You'll have to insert the EMF as an image in Word. If that still doesn't help you may have found a bug in Dia and should report it in Dia's Bugzilla in order to get it fixed (Most probably a sample diagram will be required to illustrate your problem) https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi